Can Shatter damage Manifest Mind?
The wording for Manifest Mind says:

you can cause the mind to manifest as a Tiny spectral object

And Shatter says:

A nonmagical object that isn’t being worn or carried also takes the damage if it’s in the spell’s area.

So does Manifest Mind get shattered? Or would the manifest mind count as a magical object even though the description doesn't include saying that it is magical. Or is it immune for another reason?

Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for any guidance in posting Q&A here! A gentle reminder that you should tag the question with the game and edition you are referring to, even if in this case was quite clear due to the exact wording. Happy gaming!

The text is not completely clear, but there are several clues that imply it is magical.
It is true that the description of the Manifest Mind does not say that it is magical, but it reports that

[...] it manifest[s] as a Tiny spectral object, [...]. The spectral mind is intangible and doesn’t occupy its space.

It seems that it appears as a Tiny object, not that it is a Tiny object.
Moreover, the last paragraph says:

The spectral mind stops manifesting if it is ever more than 300 feet away from you, if someone casts dispel magic on it, if the Awakened Spellbook is destroyed, if you die, or if you dismiss the spectral mind as a bonus action. Once you conjure the mind, you can’t do so again until you finish a long rest, unless you expend a spell slot of any level to conjure it again.

Dispel Magic is effective against the Manifest Mind, hence it is a strong clue that it is actually magical. Moreover, another way to conjure it is to use a spell slot of any level: per the Sage Advice Compendium, since it is fueled by a spell slot, it is magical.

The subclass description also says "a wizard in the Order of Scribes magically awakens their [spell]book", but I'm unsure if this means the mind itself is magical or just the process used to awaken it. (This matters because the Manifest Mind is just the spellbook's mind given physical form, so if the mind is magical, then so is its manifest form.)

@RyanC.Thompson yes, I was initially starting my answer with that bit, but I am unsure to justify the link between the magical awaken spellbook and the manifest mind...

The link is explicit: "You can conjure forth the mind of your Awakened Spellbook." So if "the mind" is magical, then it is still magical while manifest.

The part I'm unsure about is whether the Awakened Spellbook (and its mind) are actually magical. Because there are other ways of awakening things (e.g. the Awaken spell) that have instantaneous duration and don't create an ongoing magical effect. (However, this doesn't really matter for the case of Manifest Mind, which is still magical either way because it's powered by spell slots.)

@RyanC.Thompson I was unsure about linking the fact the fact that the awakened spellbook is magical per description and the manifestation of its sentience is magical.

@RyanC.Thompson I do believe that the awakened spell book is magical, since "Using specially prepared inks and ancient incantations passed down by your wizardly order, you have awakened an arcane sentience within your spellbook." I may add also this bit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is an indirect response to your answer in the description of the lvl 14th abilities of the Awakened Spellbook.

Moreover, if you take damage while your spellbook's mind is
manifested, you can prevent all of that damage to you by using your
reaction to dismiss the spectral mind, using its magic to save
yourself.

Using his magic to save yourself. I'm pretty sure that means it's magical :) Plus it's coming from a spellbook...

The Manifest Mind (probably) cannot be damaged or destroyed
The description for Manifest Mind does not specify that it has hit points, nor does it specify that the mind can be destroyed. It does specify several ways to cause the mind to "stop manifesting", none of which involve damaging it:

The spectral mind stops manifesting if it is ever more than 300 feet away from you, if someone casts dispel magic on it, if the Awakened Spellbook is destroyed, if you die, or if you dismiss the spectral mind as a bonus action.

You could argue that as a Tiny object, it should have hit points (ignoring for the moment whether it should be considered fragile or resilient). However, according to the DMG (and basic rules):

An object’s hit points measure how much damage it can take before losing its structural integrity.

The mind is spectral and intangible, so it has no "structural integrity" to lose. So even if it had hit points and could be damaged, there's no clear effect that would result from reducing it to zero hit points. Hence, while it's not explicitly spelled out, regardless of how you look at it, it does not seem like Shatter or anything else can destroy the Manifest Mind.
